# How to structure algorith with lots of constants?

Tags: c++, algorithm, architecture

I am working on a computer vision-based AI algorithm in `C++` and I have a lot of constants in my program.

What I have done is declared the constants as `public variables` in the `class declaration` and then initialized them in the `constructor`.

Is this a good practice?  I read some blogs and found that the other way is to create a `constants.h` file and make all the constants as a global variable.

I want to ask what the best practice to handle many constants in a huge program?

Comment: That's opinion based. Please read [tour] _"Don't ask about... Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc."_ A good reference for best practices are the [C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). Coding guidelines of most large companies (Mozilla, Google, Facebook, ...) are publicly available.

Comment: If you use the class it's probably better (IMO) to use `static` variables and initialize them directly in the definition.

Comment: If your constants are used by other parts of the program, then making them public is ok, but creating get() methods would be better. If they are used only *inside* your class, better make them private. Only expose things hat you *have* to expose. Keep the interface as small as possible.

Comment: In C++, I'd expect a `class` to implement an *algorithm*. If those constants are constant for a single execution of the algorithm, they are OK as (`const`) instance variables *only if concurrent executions may require individual/per instance values*. Opinion: If shared, but "eternal", class consts may do. If in a library to be linked dynamically, you may opt for inter-version compatibility using (eternally invariable…) *names/keys* or *accessors* of known name to some value store. (I'm not up to speed since at least C++11.)